# Soap web-service not working (PHP)

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have looked all over stack overflow and only found a couple threads related but they did not solve my problem. Also, for what it's worth, this is an LTL carrier by the name of Estes that I am trying to get this to work through.

**Here's the code I'm using:**

```
    $url = "http://www.estes-express.com/rating/ratequote/services/RateQuoteService?wsdl";
    $username = 'un';
    $password = 'pw';

    $client = new SoapClient($url);

    //Prepare SoapHeader parameters 
    $cred = array( 
        'user'      => $username, 
        'password'  => $password
    );

    $headers = new SoapHeader('http://ws.estesexpress.com/ratequote', 'auth', $cred);
    $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

    $params = array( 
        "requestID"         => "20131724",
        "account"           => "9252066",
        "originPoint"       => array('countryCode' => 'US', 'postalCode' => "43537"),
        "destinationPoint"  => array('countryCode' => 'US', 'postalCode' => "43460"),
        "payor"             => 'S',
        "terms"             => 'PPD',
        "stackable"         => 'N',
        "baseCommodities"   => array('commodity' => array('class' => "55", 'weight' => "500") )
    );

    $return = $client->getQuote(array("rateRequest"=>$params));

    return $return;
```

**Here is the response I am getting:**
[Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'requestID' property

Any help on this would be great!

PS. I have already tried putting them in stdClass() objects with not result. Also, their WSDL is in the code if you want to check it out.

**EDITED:**
Here is a dump of what the request should look like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rat="http://ws.estesexpress.com/ratequote" xmlns:rat1="http://ws.estesexpress.com/schema/2012/12/ratequote">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <rat:auth>
         <rat:user>xxxxx</rat:user>
         <rat:password>xxxxxx</rat:password>
      </rat:auth>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <rat1:rateRequest>
         <rat1:requestID>20131724</rat1:requestID>
         <rat1:account>9252066</rat1:account>
         <rat1:originPoint>
            <rat1:countryCode>US</rat1:countryCode>
            <rat1:postalCode>43537</rat1:postalCode>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <rat1:city>Maumee</rat1:city>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <rat1:stateProvince>OH</rat1:stateProvince>
         </rat1:originPoint>
         <rat1:destinationPoint>
            <rat1:countryCode>US</rat1:countryCode>
            <rat1:postalCode>23237</rat1:postalCode>
            <rat1:stateProvince>VA</rat1:stateProvince>
         </rat1:destinationPoint>
         <rat1:payor>S</rat1:payor>
         <rat1:terms>PPD</rat1:terms>
         <rat1:stackable>N</rat1:stackable>
         <rat1:baseCommodities>
            <!--1 to 99 repetitions:-->
            <rat1:commodity>
               <rat1:class>50</rat1:class>
               <rat1:weight>100</rat1:weight>
            </rat1:commodity>
         </rat1:baseCommodities>
      </rat1:rateRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: It seems completely obvious that there is something wrong with your `getQuote` function. Could you get a dump of all your params / headers and share those?

Comment: Did you check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269268/soap-error-encoding-object-has-no-recordid-property

Comment: Anup, yes unfortunately and it didn't solve the problem. itcouldevenbeaboat I edited my values in my question to show you the actual values and added a request example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This caught me out the other day, too: the parameters expected by the SoapClients called should *not* include the outermost XML tag within the body, in this case `rateRequest`, as this is generated automatically based on the description in the WSDL. Instead, you need to pass a structure (array or object) containing each of the parameters defined *within* that outer tag.

So in your case, you just need to change this:

```
$return = $client->getQuote(array("rateRequest"=>$params));
```

to this:

```
$return = $client->getQuote($params);
```

Incidentally, your code as pasted also has a typo where you define `$headers` but then reference `$header`. A [live demo with both changes](http://codepad.viper-7.com/8EKKMG) shows instead a "User authentication failed." fault (presumably because you were wise enough not to give us your real login details!)

Comment: Thanks a bunch IMSoP!! That was exactly the issue and they happen to put a weight cap on the WS that was giving me a soapFault "general error" ;).

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still having trouble with this, in order to get this to work I had to change the $params into an object or else I would receive an error, "Object Property Does Not Exist"

```
$params = new stdClass();
$params->requestID = "20131724";
$params->account = "123456";
$params->originPoint = array('countryCode' => 'US', 'postalCode' => "43537");
$params->destinationPoint = array('countryCode' => 'US', 'postalCode' => "43460");
$params->payor = "S";
$params->terms = "PPD";
$params->stackable = "N";
$params->baseCommodities = array('commodity' => array('class' => "55", 'weight' => "100") );

$return = $client->getQuote($params);
```